# Enable tilde trigger with Akka and sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

With sbt it is possible to do ~run to recompile and run the program when the source changes. However once an ActorSystem is created it does not work anymore.

When the system is shutdown it works, but I don't want to shutdown the system.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem()

    // if this line is removed, source code detection is disabled
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that SBTs `~run` by itself is *not* hot-reloading, it is simply "once the process finishes, run it again please". Akka's thread-pools are non-daemonic, which means that until the ActorSystem is "alive" the program will not terminate, thus SBT's `~run` won't trigger again.

Instead you might want to look into the [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) SBT plugin, which can do what you're looking for (including for Akka based apps).

Comment: Thanks for your answer